# loop failed, It won't increase the number, android studio

Tags: android, database, loops, android-sqlite

can you guys help me to check where is the problem? I put a loop for the **LastTxnNo**, But it won't increase automatically. This is initialize database.

```
dbHelper = new dbOpenHelper(this);
        mSQLiteHelper = new dbOpenHelper(this);
        mModels = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdapter = new settingAdapter(this, R.layout.row_setting, mModels);
        listView1.setAdapter(mAdapter);
```

I have two tables, This is the 'Donation_Details' table, the TxnNo should be 'A0010001' or '0001'
[image]

and this is the 'Information' table

[image]

'Donation_Details' TxnNo should be 'Information' unitcode+lastTxnNo, means
TxnNo should 'A0010001'. and when i click the button, the lastTxnNo will increase, and it will change to 'A0010002'. But I think I missed some logic.

```
 Db_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Model txn = new Model();// initialize your model class first
                SettingModel txnSec = new SettingModel();

                BigDecimal paidAmt = new BigDecimal(D_Amount.getText().toString()).setScale(2, RoundingMode.HALF_UP);
                txn.setName(D_Name.getText().toString());
                txnSec.setLastTxnNo(D_Txn.getText().toString());
                txn.setTxnDate(Select_Date.getText().toString());
                txn.setAmount(paidAmt);
                txn.setDescription1(D_Description.getSelectedItem().toString());
                txn.setDescription2(Ds_Description.getText().toString());

                try {
                    SQLiteDatabase db = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
                    cv.put("name", txn.getName());
                    cv.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", i));
                    cv.put("TxnDate", txn.getTxnDate());
                    cv.put("Amount", txn.getAmount().toPlainString());
                    cv.put("Description1", txn.getDescription1());
                    cv.put("Description2", txn.getDescription2());
                    db.insert("Donation_Details", null, cv);
                    db.close();

                    SharedPreferences app_preferences = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Donation_Page.this);
                    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = app_preferences.edit();
                    int i = app_preferences.getInt("key", 0);
                    i = ++i;
                    txnSec.setLastTxnNo(i + "");
                    SQLiteDatabase dbSec = dbHelper.getWritableDatabase();
                    ContentValues cvSec = new ContentValues();
                    cvSec.put("TxnNo", String.format("%04d", i));
                    editor.putInt("key", i).commit();
                    dbSec.insert("Information", null, cvSec);
                    dbSec.close();

                    Toast.makeText(Donation_Page.this, "Add successfully", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have declared the variable inside method which is getting the value from `preference` so every time the new local variable(redeclare with button press) get value `0` from preference so either

- Declare `i` outside method
- or save the update value back to preference

```
int i = app_preferences.getInt("key", 0);
i++; // no need of i = ++i;
editor.putInt("key",i);
editor.commit(); // save value into preference
```

or use

```
// declare i outside method
private int i = 0;

... someMethod(){
    Db_Save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                // ... code

                        i++;
                // ... code
                }
            });
  }
```

Comment: So I better don't use `editor.putInt("key", i).commit();` ?

Comment: @LeonZaii we have to use editor to save values, see the updated answer, though avoid preference if you don't need the value outside activity, they are costly

Comment: @Pavneet_Singh Why  `i = -1` for  the second approach  ?

Comment: @JohnJoe it's just happened, I thought OP wants the count from `0` , not required, letme change it, thanks